# VST Synths for creepy atmosphere in OSX

Tags: synthesizer, recommendations, vst, osx, atmosphere

I'm looking for VST-based synthesizers which are suited to making creepy or scary atmospheric sounds.

I'm looking for 32bit and OSX compatible plugins.

Any recommendation is welcome.

Comment: I've used Alchemy from Camel Audio, which is awesome. Then Octopus does also good work at atmospheric sounds. Any other would be very useful.

Comment: I don't know of any VSTis for this, I'd just use my usuals. Spooky chords and weird note combinations are the most effective part for me. You could make any sound "creepy" with the right notes I think.

Comment: How the vst is built in (design) and how are the lfo or envelopes mapped each other with some oscillator parameters, for example in the VST matrix, makes a huge difference in the kind of sound they generate. Making some of them more suitable for atmospheric strings, pads or just texture Fx. Thanks for your help, but I'm asking for VST instruments not really techniques on how to create sound.

Answer (score 1):

I have Native Instruments Komplete 10. Out of those synths, the best suited for creepy/scary atmospheric sounds would be

**Absynth 5**

This is a standard subtractive/additive synthesizer. It has filters, it has LFOs, and it has a great Envelope editor that can support a ton of nodes within the loop section. One of the bigger aspects of Absynth that makes it good for creepy/scary is the mutation function. You can mutate sounds over and over and get into some strange sounds.

**FM 8**

This is a frequency modulation synth. FM is great for getting metallic sounds. Creepy atmospheric gongs are really easy with this.

**Reactor 5**

I love reactor because you can make any kind of synth you want with it. If anything can make a sound, reactor can. It requires a lot of knowledge and setup time to get what you want though. In Reactor, I would recommend making a granular synthesizer and load a whole song in. Getting the almost a song, but not really sound could work really well atmospherically. Granular synthesis of any kind is highly recommended.

That's just NI though. There are soooo manyyy software synthesizers, not even including the ones that emulate hardware synthesizers.

Comment: Those are some of my usuals lol! Love them.